# ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: vb.net, odbc, ms-access-2010

This is driving me crazy and I am hoping that someone can help me.  I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 and am making a Windows Form application in VB to access data in a MS Access 2010 database.  This is done using an ODBC Microsoft Access Driver.  I originally had all my SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT statements built out as a string.  I went back and changed them to parameter based commands to handle special characters and to eliminate the database insertion threat.  All works fine except for one query.

Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
Dim cmdSQLQuery As Odbc.OdbcCommand
cmdSQLQuery = SCCResources.dbConnSCCResources.CreateCommand

cmdSQLQuery.CommandText = "SELECT tblRepairRequests.ID as [Repair Request ID #], tblRepairRequests.RequestType as [Request Type], tblRepairRequests.PositionLocation as [Position #], tblRepairRequests.DateTimeSubmitted as [Date/Time Submitted], tblRepairRequests.DateTimeClosed as [Date/Time Closed], tblRepairRequests.Status, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterFirstName as [Submitter's First Name], tblRepairRequests.SubmitterLastName as [Submitter's Last Name], tblRepairRequests.SubmitterIDNumber as [Submitter's ID #], tblRepairRequests.SupervisorFirstName as [Supervisor First Name], tblRepairRequests.SupervisorLastName as [Supervisor Last Name], tblRepairRequests.SupervisorIDNumber as [Supervisor ID #], tblRepairRequests.ProblemDescription as [Problem Description], tblRepairRequests.DuplicateParent, tblRepairRequests.DuplicateChild, tblRepairRequests.Reopened FROM tblRepairRequests WHERE tblRepairRequests.ID = ?; "
cmdSQLQuery.Parameters.Clear()
cmdSQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", ID.Text)
cmdSQLQuery.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim daSearchResults As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmdSQLQuery)
Dim dsSearchResults As New System.Data.DataSet
Dim dvSearchResults As New System.Data.DataView

daSearchResults.Fill(dsSearchResults)
dvSearchResults = dsSearchResults.Tables(0).DefaultView

With dgvSearchResults
    .DataSource = dvSearchResults
        .Columns("Status").Visible = True
        .Columns("DuplicateParent").Visible = False
        .Columns("DuplicateChild").Visible = False
        .Columns("Reopened").Visible = False
        .Columns("Repair Request ID #").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Request Type").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Status").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Submitter's First Name").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Submitter's Last Name").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Submitter's ID #").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Date/Time Submitted").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Date/Time Submitted").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        .Columns("Supervisor First Name").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Supervisor Last Name").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Supervisor ID #").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Position #").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Problem Description").Width = 300
        .Columns("Date/Time Closed").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns("Date/Time Closed").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        .ReadOnly = True
        .Visible = True
End With
```

At the line **daSearchResults.Fill(dsSearchResults)** I get the following error: *ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.*
I know named parameters are not fully supported, in other words being able to add in any order. I am using them for easy readability and I am adding them in the right order.  My watch on the command shows the parameter there.  If I use the following string query, it works fine:

```
strSQLQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT tblRepairRequests.ID as [Repair Request ID #], tblRepairRequests.RequestType as [Request Type], tblRepairRequests.PositionLocation as [Position #], tblRepairRequests.DateTimeSubmitted as [Date/Time Submitted], tblRepairRequests.DateTimeClosed as [Date/Time Closed], tblRepairRequests.Status, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterFirstName as [Submitter's First Name], tblRepairRequests.SubmitterLastName as [Submitter's Last Name], tblRepairRequests.SubmitterIDNumber as [Submitter's ID #], tblRepairRequests.SupervisorFirstName as [Supervisor First Name], tblRepairRequests.SupervisorLastName as [Supervisor Last Name], tblRepairRequests.SupervisorIDNumber as [Supervisor ID #], tblRepairRequests.ProblemDescription as [Problem Description], tblRepairRequests.DuplicateParent, tblRepairRequests.DuplicateChild, tblRepairRequests.Reopened FROM tblRepairRequests WHERE tblRepairRequests.ID = 3;"
```

I don't know what is wrong especially since this similar code works on another form in the same program on the same database:

```
    If SCCResources.CheckDBConnStateOpen(1) Then
                Dim cmdSubmitRepairRequest As Odbc.OdbcCommand
                cmdSubmitRepairRequest = SCCResources.dbConnSCCResources.CreateCommand
                With cmdSubmitRepairRequest

                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblRepairRequests([RequestType], [SubmitterFirstName], [SubmitterLastName], [SubmitterIDNumber], [DateTimeSubmitted], [SupervisorFirstName], [SupervisorLastName], [SupervisorIDNumber], [PositionLocation], [ProblemDescription], [Status], [DuplicateParent], [DuplicateChild], [Reopened]) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                    .Parameters.Clear()
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("RequestType", cbRequestType.SelectedValue)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("SubmitterFirstName", dtReportingUserList.Rows(cbPersonReporting.SelectedIndex).Item("FirstName"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("SubmitterLastName", dtReportingUserList.Rows(cbPersonReporting.SelectedIndex).Item("LastName"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("SubmitterIDNumber", dtReportingUserList.Rows(cbPersonReporting.SelectedIndex).Item("SheriffID"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("DateTimeSubmitted", Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " " & TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("SupervisorFirstName", dtSupervisorContactedList.Rows(cbSupervisorContacted.SelectedIndex).Item("FirstName"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("SupervisorLastName", dtSupervisorContactedList.Rows(cbSupervisorContacted.SelectedIndex).Item("LastName"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("SupervisorIDNumber", dtSupervisorContactedList.Rows(cbSupervisorContacted.SelectedIndex).Item("SheriffID"))
                    If cbPositionLocation.SelectedValue = "" Then
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("PositionLocation", "")
                    Else
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("PositionLocation", cbPositionLocation.SelectedValue)
                    End If
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("ProblemDescription", tbProblemDescription.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", "Open")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("DuplicateParent", False)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("DuplicateChild", False)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("Reopened", False)

                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()

                    .CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity"
                    MessageBox.Show("The repair request has been submitted.  The request number is: " & cmdSubmitRepairRequest.ExecuteScalar(), "Repair Request Submitted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End With
End If
```

I have tried using a different name for the parameter with no change.  Nothing I seem to do (short of using a string based query) seems to work.  Very frustrating especially since similar code works in my program.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you replace ID.Text with 3?

Comment: I have tried that and the same thing happens. I tried 3 both as a string and an integer.....same error.

Comment: So, the only difference between what worked and what didn't is when you add the value of ID.Text as a parameter versus adding "3" as the value of the parameter?

Comment: No. It does not work as a parameter at all. It makes no difference if I use ID.Text as the parameter value or hard code the parameter value. The only way I can get it to work is to build the query as a string rather than use parameters and that works with either ID.Text or a hard coded value.

Comment: Just for the sake of troubleshooting, can you try adding your param like this (assuming it is an integer): cmdSQLQuery.Parameters.Add("ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(ID.Text)

Comment: Same error message. I see in the watch that the parameter was added as an integer as it had been before but for some reason it does not pull it.